# Cognito UserPoolDomain A record Aliast target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an a record alias dns entry in my hostedZone and assign it to a Cognito user pool domain using cloudformation but I keep getting this error

```
Custom domain is not a valid subdomain: Was not able to resolve the root domain, please ensure an A record exists for the root domain.
```

Here is my template resource

```
CognitoARecord:
Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
Properties:
  HostedZoneId: !Ref myDNSRecordHostedZone
  Name: !Ref AuthDomainName
  AliasTarget:
    HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
    DNSName: !GetAtt 'ESRVUserPoolDomain.CloudFrontDistribution'
    EvaluateTargetHealth: "false"
  TTL: !Ref TTL
  Type: A

ESRVUserPoolDomain:
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain
Properties:
  Domain: !Ref AuthDomainName
  UserPoolId: !Ref ESRVCognitoUserPool
  CustomDomainConfig:
    CertificateArn: !Ref ACM
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm running into such an issue. I'd appreciate ant help